# Making windows terminal color more like putty

Tags: putty, windows-terminal, vimdiff

How to make color in windows terminal same as putty which I am more use to, in the default color scheme in windows terminal many text are not clearly visible in utilities like vimdiff, I tried other color schemes like vintage but it still doesn't work, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/color-schemes